# Profile doesn't include aps-evironmentProd, Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, signing

I am trying to start my app on a device and faced with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqZPW.png). It doesn't depend on signing method. Push notifications feature enabled for the App ID in Developer account, valid APNS certs added. On the capabilities tab [everything is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW7kY.png).

I know what is aps-environment (this string presents in [generated profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho1ly.png)), but what does Xcode mean by environmentProd string? I can't find out just anything about "aps-evironmentProd".

The application started without any troubles on previous Xcode versions. For me it seems like regular Xcode bug. How can I handle this without Xcode downgrade?

[Entitlements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Aii.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have changed/updated `APS Environment` to `APS EnvironmentProd` in your `.entitlements` file.

Check your `.entitlements` again to be sure. If not just restart Xcode.

Also, I am assuming you already know following:
No need to update `development` to `production in`.entitlements`. Because we can't use the production certificate in debug/development.
When we do 'Archive' Xcode automatically set it to production.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The fact is, I didn't edit entitlements. Before this problem started, I used the same provisioning profiles which was just generated at developer.apple.com.

Comment: Also, I remembered I have xcode 9.2. Problem does not appear on it. Weird.

Comment: Talking about updating 'development' to 'production' I didn't do this.

Comment: @lesha-native can you share you `.entitlements` files code?

Comment: I've uploaded the screen into the description. It's not exact .entitlements, but .mobileprovision

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old question but still I wanted to provide an answer as I had same problem.
I did try so many options, recreated provisions, certificates edit manually entitlements and nothing worked.
At the end I created new project with same name as my original app did all setup a nd there was no eny error for entitlements.
I have Uploaded app into appstoreconnect and tested all worked fine.
Then I copied entitlements file and appdelegeate into my original app and no errors after.